# Putting 2 divs under each other with Bootstrap flex classes

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

You can see my problem on the uploaded image. Within that, the first image.

When I minimize the browser screen width these two divs won't get under each other, just when the window is fully minimized, or when i view the site on mobile.

When the window is too small, so the 2 divs can reach each other, I want them under each other.

I tried media queries, but I think I can do this with only a few Bootstrap classes, and that will be better.

[image]

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section class="header_full_width py-2 px-4">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-center justify-content-lg-between">
      <div>
        <a href="tel:+3630" class="text-white_disabled header_full_width_link text-white_redundant" title="Hívás"><i class="fa fa-phone mr-1 mr-md-2"></i>Kérdésed van? +36 30 123 4567</a>
      </div>
      
      <div>
        <span class="text-white_disabled header_full_width_link text-white_redundant"><i class="fa fa-envelope mr-1 mr-md-2"></i>info@emailcimem.hu</span>
        <span class="nav_separator_2 text-white mx-1">|</span>
        
        <a href="kapcsolat" class="text-white_disabled header_full_width_link text-white_redundant" title="Elérhetőségeink"><i class="fa fa-phone-square mr-1 mr-md-2"></i>Kapcsolat</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Why am I not seeing you use a `col-` class on your `row` children? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/layout/grid/

Comment: What are "these two divs"? We can't read your mind. Please revise to be more clear about your goal. This appears to be a carousel, so be sure to explain how that relates.

Comment: There are 2 divs in the row div.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use bootstrap's `row` and `col` classes.
As we can already see, in your code example above. You have used `row` but not `col` for the children `div`'s

A bootstrap `row` is considered to have `12` units. So for both the `div`'s you can give class of `col-12 col-lg-6`. Bootstrap takes a mobile first approach so this means, the `div`'s will take full width of the row till the screen size reaches `lg` (992px), then the `div`'s will occupy half each i.e. 6 units each.

"When the window is too small, so the 2 `div`'s can reach each other, I want them under each other."

To answer this - you can choose when you want your `div`'s to share the row. Just replace `lg` with the appropriate breakpoint by refrencing the image below.

[image]

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <section class="header_full_width py-2 px-4">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-center justify-content-lg-between">
          <div class='col-12 col-lg-6'>
            <a href="tel:+3630" class="text-white_disabled header_full_width_link text-white_redundant" title="Hívás"><i class="fa fa-phone mr-1 mr-md-2"></i>Kérdésed van? +36 30 123 4567</a>
          </div>
          
          <div class='col-12 col-lg-6'>
            <span class="text-white_disabled header_full_width_link text-white_redundant"><i class="fa fa-envelope mr-1 mr-md-2"></i>info@emailcimem.hu</span>
            <span class="nav_separator_2 text-white mx-1">|</span>
            
            <a href="kapcsolat" class="text-white_disabled header_full_width_link text-white_redundant" title="Elérhetőségeink"><i class="fa fa-phone-square mr-1 mr-md-2"></i>Kapcsolat</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```